# Import data into excel that doesn't use a line break as a row delimiter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, import

Is there any simple method that doesn't resort to macros whereby a plain text file or string can be imported into excel without using a line break as a row delimiter?

Example

```
11,12,13;21,22,23;31,32,33
```

A string in this format, and with approximately one million rows and 20 columns is being returned by an application. I need the simplest way to load this into excel.

**Solution 1**: Import with `;` as the delimiter, paste transpose the columns, and then use 'text to columns' feature to convert all the comma delimited cells in the one column into many columns. This doesn't work because excel only supports a little over 16,000 columns, and we have many more rows than that.

**Solution 2**: Load the string into an advanced text editor that supports replacing the `;` with a line break. (Most simple text editors only support simple text replace, no line breaks.) I would have trouble instructing a business user how to do this, and am not aware of any such tools that they are likely to have on their windows machine.

Can anyone else propose a simple way to deal with this miserable data format? As far as I know, there's no way to specify a row delimiter other than line break when importing into excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Microsoft Word as per your solution 2, it's probably already in your business users PC.
The newline is indicated as ^l. See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/95474/en-us

Answer (score 2):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can be used with solution 2 rather easily.  In addition to plain text find and replace, it can also use escape strings (such as \t for tab, \n for new line), and can also do regex replacements.

You'd want to do something similar to the following:[image: Notepad++ find and replace dialog]

Comment: Not a bad program for the average Joe to have either.

Comment: Addition: Microsoft Word can find and replace `;` with `^p` to create line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Other" delimiter with value "0010". This will not be visible on the screen but works and splits the new line separated values of a cell in text to column use.